# Vert.x Proxy Service - handle routing on different machiens

Tags: java, proxy, vert.x

I got a webserver with 2 endpoints that I want to handle on different machines. They are independent and when updating one I don't want to restart the other.

```
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/api*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.post("/api/end_point_1").handler(new Handler1());
    router.post("/api/end_point_2").handler(new Handler2());
```

How can I achieve this in Vert.x? I been reading about [Vert.x Service Proxy](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/)
But I am not quite sure how to apply it to Router.

Comment: So you meant you want to process something in `server1` when `/api/end_point_1` is hit and to process another something in `server23` when `/api/end_point_2` is hit? Basically the whole thing can be distributed, but you always have the event bus; you can send the info (or nothing) to an address and do there what you want. The listener can be on the same server, on another one, or distributed (and shared).

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't right now. But if you have something already running you can communicate those through the [event bus](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus). The important thing there is to realize that the event bus will allow you to communicate different parts on the application, irrespective of what language they are written in, and whether they're in the same Vert.x instance or in a different Vert.x instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Vertx cluster.

Your handlers would look something like this:

```
router.post("/api/end_point_1").handler(req -> {
   // Extract data from request
   // Package it into an object

   // Send it over EventBus
   vertx.eventBus().send("event1", data);
});
```

Now create another verticle in a separate application, which should do:

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer("event1");
    consumer.handler(o -> {
        System.out.println("Got message" + o.body());           
    });
```

Now to run those separate Jars follow this guide: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/

Comment: Can the data in the first code block be the req object? I would like to handle the parsing and input validation on the second code block

Comment: It doesn't block by default.

Comment: lol, code block = code part. Can the data in the first code part be the req object? Can the "data" that you wrote be replaced with "req" that you wrote?

Comment: It can, but it shouldn't. Request object by itself is huge. If you try to send it, Vertx will try to serialize it completely. Send JsonObject instead.

Comment: So I must handle all the parsing in just one server? Sounds like not the optimal solution

Comment: Of course not. You can send raw body data as string or even a byte buffer over the EventBus. Just don't send RequestContext as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply package the code as two different JARs and deploy them independently. Then a load-balancer/API gateway/reverse-proxy would send the traffic to the right servers depending on the request URI.